# Is there a way I can redirect a line of code to another in Python?

Tags: python, while-loop, python-3.7

I know that the question is quite ambiguous, so I'll expand on my problem. I have written a short thingy over here as practice since I just started learning python and am sort of a newbie.

In my code, I ask the user how many apples they have and if they would like to eat it. If they keep saying "Y" until the amount of apples is 0 (`#mention 1` in the screenshot), I want my code to redirect to the `#redirect 1` part, instead of writing the entire code from `#redirect 1` again. I know that I could just rewrite it, however, I can't for the next part. If there are no apples, I ask the user if they want to buy them and the amount.

Then I would like to redirect the code back to `#redirect 2` so that the code plays out again. I have read previous questions and understand that a 'goto' doesn't exist as it is unstructured, however, I have no idea how else I would write my code. Sorry for the dumb question, but as I said I am new to this.

[image: Image of my code]

Comment: Please post *all code as formatted text in the question itself.* Dont post images of code or links to code / images of code. Always provide a [mcve] for debugging questions.

Comment: Anyway, no, there is no goto statement in Python, because it was a language made within the last, oh, 50 years. Generally, you should use *functions* to re-use code. Other than that, it is just getting used to thinking in terms of the branching/looping constructs provided by the language.

Comment: Check `while` structure https://realpython.com/python-while-loop/

Comment: Maybe not a direct duplicate, but you might find this question helpful, along with functions as previously suggested: [Asking the user for input until they give a valid response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response)

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga oh ok I’m sorry it’s my first question on stack Overflow as well so I thought a picture was enough

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you need function definition. Something like.

```
def dostuff():
    print "doing stuff"
    num = 0
num = 0
while true:
    num =+ 1
    if num == 5:
        dostuff()
    else:
        pass
```

This should print doing stuff once every 5 loops

Comment: How would I apply it in this case? If the number of apples is 0 and I ask the user if they want to buy more apples, I want the loop to repeat again. Should I use the while loop?

Comment: `while true:`
will cause anything inside of it to loop forever until you call a `break`
You can check the user input, and if the input is no you `break` the loop because they don't want to buy more. In your case you'd use `while true:` choice and it would be inside the `if apples > 0:`